# Executing scripts in order using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, bash, mysqli, ssh2-exec

I have a website that lets user select test scripts from radio buttons, and after submitting the desired test to the remote server, using PHP:

1. It inserts sends a row into MySQL database in the test_activity_log table, with id, username, test name, gateway name, and timestamp.
2. It then sends a `ssh2_exec` to execute the desired script on the remote gateway

Everything above I already have working, however, in the case when multiple users are executing scripts from the webpage simultaneously, I need to find a way to queue them up in order and execute them one after another. What would be the best way to do this?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

testexe.php

```
<?php

...
...    

//while there are still jobs that are not done..
while (1) {
    //wait for 10 seconds and query again...
    sleep(10);
    $statusResult = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $qStatus);
    //if there are undone jobs we pick them and execute them
    if (mysqli_num_rows($statusResult) > 0){
        //query the next undone test case
        $testResult = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $qNextTest);

        //fetch the returned query object and store needed parameters 
        $row = $testResult->fetch_assoc();
        $id = $row['id'];               
        $test_script = $row['test_script']; 
        $gateway = $row['gateway'];         


        if ($connection = @ssh2_connect($gateway, 22)) {
            ssh2_auth_password($connection, $user, $password);

            //execute the test case
            $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, "/my/path/to/script.sh"); 

            //fetch output stream and stderr
            stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
            $stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
            $stream_err = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR);
            while($line = fgets($stream_out)) {flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}               
            echo '<pre>' . "------------------------\n" . '</pre>';
            while($line = fgets($stream_err)) {flush(); echo '<pre>' . $line . '</pre>';}
            fclose($stream);    

            //update the table after the above script is done
            $qUpdateStatus = "UPDATE table SET status = 1 WHERE id = $id";
            $updateresult = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $qUpdateStatus);
        }

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Look into using something like [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). You push jobs onto a queue, then read them off sequentially in a different process (PHP or otherwise). You would generally then kill off the initial PHP script, and start polling an end-point that reports the status of the given job (via AJAX, etc)

Comment: Agree on using a queue of some kind. Another job queue that is popular in the PHP community is [Gearman](http://gearman.org/).

Comment: @iainn Ok, thanks for that. I was also thinking to add a `done` column the mysql table, and query for the `done=1` before executing the next script in a `while loop` do you think this would work?

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for that, I brought up a suggestion to iainn above, I was wondering if something like that would work?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour, it can work but only if you have just one script-runner checking for `done=0` and updating to `done=1`. Otherwise you'll get race conditions.

Comment: Hey @BillKarwin, your comment seems like a viable solution. However, could you provide a simple example of a scriptrunner youwere saying, or could you elaborate more one this. Is this basically just a php file that gets called constantly and checked the table for done?

Comment: @kkmoslehpour, right, typically it's a script that either runs on a schedule, or runs all the time, with its own loop, in which it checks for any data needed to be processed, processes them, and then sleeps for some amount of time. The loop solution can be better, because if you use a scheduler, the time the script runs might become longer than the schedule interval and then you'd have more than one running at the same time.

Comment: @BillKarwin Hey Bill, after your suggestion, I've been working on this code (added above). However, I have a question, how can php script be called? Or when you mean it runs all the time, how can I make it run all the time? do i have to run it like `php testexe.php` on the server first or? cause I know this script just listen to events, in my case the events are `done=0`, but how can i keep this script running all the time? I don't quite get this part..